# Identify the timestamps of the merged audio signal

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, signal-processing, speech

I have an audio file which was created by substituting multiple speech segments into an original (speech) utterance. The two speakers sound quite similar to each other.
I want to find the timestamps where such substitutions happened, so I guess that one thing I can do is looking for the abrupt changes in the audio waveform.

By visualizing the waveform, I have something like below. There was a sudden shift in the middle of the figure, which implies the fusion of the two speech segments.

```python
fig, (ax, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharex=True)
ax.set(xlim=[1.5, 1.6], title='Sample view', ylim=[-1, 1])
y, sr = librosa.load("example.wav", sr=None,duration=10)
y_harm, y_perc = librosa.effects.hpss(y)
librosa.display.waveshow(y, sr=sr, ax=ax, marker='.', label='Full signal')
librosa.display.waveshow(y_harm, sr=sr, alpha=0.5, ax=ax2, label='Harmonic')
librosa.display.waveshow(y_perc, sr=sr, color='r', alpha=0.5, ax=ax2, label='Percussive')
```

[image: waveform visualization]

I found some answer [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/83813/how-to-identify-sudden-changes-in-signals) and [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/66380/detect-abrupt-changes-in-signal) which suggested

> differentiate the signal numerically and threshold the magnitude of
> differentiate to identify the abrupt changes

I have tried using the sliding window and threshold to find such changes but the result was not as expected with too many false positives.

**My question is:** how to find such abrupt changes and **their timestamps** programmatically by using any (maybe, python-based) open-source tools? Machine learning-based approaches are welcome too.

Note that the segment merged done by waveform overlapping and the amplitude is [normalized](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-G.191/en). I think it will make it harder to locate such fusion points. I am not sure I used to right terms for this. Please suggest the right ones if you I think there are proper terms to denote what I have described so far.

Comment: It is not trivial task. Speech itself has abrupt changes. Unless your task is somewhat simplified, I think ML approaches are the only reasonable way to go. Use Librispeech and/or other free speech databases to create your own train/test datasets.

Comment: @dankal444 yes I do have my a sufficiently large training set with the timestamps of each segment for each utterances. Could you suggest some algorithms (and if possible, open-source tools) to train a model that produces a desired output?

Comment: Neural Networks in `tensorflow` or `pytorch`. When it comes to good architecture, I am not up-to-date with current state-of-the-art models, so I suggest some googling. Somewhat related problems I found [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0925231220312960) and [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2209.07498.pdf). You may want to use their network archiitectures as a starting point.